# C# Equivalent of openssl dgst -sha256 -sign Command

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, signature

Currently I'm using this command to generate signature for my request:

```
printf '%s' <json string> | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign <private key path> | base64
```

Is there an equivalent in C# for this command? I've searched online for the entire afternoon but no luck.

Currently I have this:

```
private static string SignClaim(string claim)
    {
        var claimBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(claim);
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKey));
        using var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        var signedBytes = rsa.SignData(claimBytes, new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider());
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
    }
```

But at the X509 constructor it says "cannot find requested object"

Comment: Ultimately, this question comes down to "how do I load an RSA private key from a file?" (because after that you just want `rsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)`), which has been asked many times (because, sadly, it's not super easy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Read .Key file on C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962625/how-to-read-key-file-on-c)